# Как найти значение в дереве?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

У меня есть DepartmentDigestDto, выглядит так:

```
public class DepartmentDigestDto
{
    [JsonProperty( PropertyName = "id" )]
    [JsonRequired]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty( PropertyName = "title" )]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty( PropertyName = "parent_department_id" )]
    public string ParentDepartmentId { get; set; }
}
```

Это один из возвращаемых объектов метода List:

```
var departments = ( await _departmentClient.List().Unwrap() ).Items;
```

Мне на вход отдают id, а я должен найти в департаментах путь до этого id, т.е как-то так:
Office/firstRoom/etc.. (где названия - это Title)
Мне показалось, что можно преобразовать в дерево, поэтому сделал следующее:

```
static internal class Extensions
{
    static public IEnumerable<ExtensionTreeItem<T>> GenerateTree<T, K>(
        this IEnumerable<T> collection,
        Func<T, K> idSelector,
        Func<T, K> parentIdSelector,
        K rootId = default( K ) )
    {
        foreach ( var item in collection
            .Where( item => EqualityComparer<K>.Default
                .Equals( parentIdSelector( item ), rootId ) ) )
        {
            yield return new ExtensionTreeItem<T>
            {
                Item = item,
                Children = collection.GenerateTree(
                    idSelector,
                    parentIdSelector,
                    idSelector( item ) )
            };
        }
    }
}

internal class ExtensionTreeItem<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ExtensionTreeItem<T>> Children { get; set; }
}
```

А потом это вызывается вот таким образом:

```
var departmentsTree = departments
    .GenerateTree(
        department => department.Id,
        department => department.ParentDepartmentId )
    .ToDictionary( x => ( x.Item.Id, x.Item.Title), x => x.Children );
```

Получается, что ключом в словаре, является самое начало пути, а конец где-то в value находится.
Вопрос: как получить этот путь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понятно, зачем вам все эти циклы, обертки и прочее. У вас ваши данные уже представляют собой узлы, обертки им не нужны. Собрать дерево/граф можно в виде обычного словаря, где id - ключ, узел - значение. Путь можно собрать, если идти снизу вверх и потом сам путь перевернуть. Вот пример

Пример данных

```
var data = new DepartmentDigestDto[] {
    new DepartmentDigestDto() {Id = "1", Title = "Office" },
    new DepartmentDigestDto() {Id = "2", Title = "First Room", ParentDepartmentId = "1" },
    new DepartmentDigestDto() {Id = "3", Title = "Second Room", ParentDepartmentId = "2" },
    };
```

Собираем дерево (называю деревом с допущением, что у вас в данных нет циклов)

```
var tree = data.ToDictionary(x => x.Id);
```

Исходная комната, от которой ищем

```
var roomId = "3";
```

Строим путь снизу вверх, складываем его в стек. Стек- потому что потом надо надо пройтись по пути в обратном направлении

```
var path = new Stack<string>();
path.Push(roomId);
while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tree[path.Peek()].ParentDepartmentId))
    path.Push(tree[path.Peek()].ParentDepartmentId);
```

В коде выше я не учитываю циклы. Защита от циклов пусть будет домашним заданием =)

Ну и вывод пути сверху вниз

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("/", path.Select(x => tree[x].Title)));
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
Office/First Room/Second Room
```

Comment: такое простое и хорошее решение, спасибо. Скажите, а если мне передадут несколько id, то, наверное, лучше объявить List<Stack<string>> и в них пушить, да?

Comment: что значит несколько id? если там для каждого надо путь найти, то поиск пути выведите в отдельную функцию, передавайте туда tree и ваш roomId и вычисляйте путь для каждого переданного вам айдишника по отдельности.

Comment: обертки мне нужны были для того, чтобы можно было потом удобно еще и id достать
т.е вот мне передадут какие-то id, я по ним найду все связанные подразделения и выведу пути

Comment: ну, вы видите, я сделал то же самое, но без оберток. Я просто храню айдишники в пути и всё работает. То есть обертки не нужны )

Comment: хорошо, а что вы будете делать, если вам понадобится вывести, помимо путей, еще и все nested подразделения (их id)? не могу как-то из вашего решения это вывести
подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: что буду делать, если будет другая задача? Буду её решать :) Вы в своем вопросе обозначили вашу задачу, я показал её решение. Если вы в полете находите новые задачи - то задавайте другой вопрос, у него будет другое решение

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь;)

Comment: на всякий случай хинт: если вам надо по roomId найти все дочерние комнаты, то рассмотрите вариант создания словаря, где ключ - roomId, значение - это все комнаты, у которых parentId равен ключу. По такому словарю можно быстро собрать все nested узлы без проблем.